# Highlight the row of a table on mouseover using Javascript and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Below is are the functions I'm using in order to highlight a row being hovered over.

I am having trouble understanding how this can be achieved when my goal is to select the tbodies from the stripe_table class.  Once this is set as the event listener, I need to have the a and td nodeNames respond to the mouseover event and thus highlight their parent row.

Can someone explain the steps that would allow this to be accomplished?  How would I traverse the DOM from the hovered a or td element to find its parent row?

Thanks!

Set tbody as eventlistener on mouseover and mouseout
reacts to a and td elements-->modifies tr
--find the target element’s ancestor table row 
--so that you apply the highlighting to that table row
--To traverse the DOM run a loop that resets the event
--target element to its parent node until the node name of the
--parent is equal to 
On mouseout event, need to restore the formatting*/

```
//Set up Hover Events

function addEvent( obj, type, fn ) {

    if ( obj.attachEvent ) {
         obj['e'+type+fn] = fn;
         obj[type+fn] = function(){obj['e'+type+fn] ( window.event );}
         obj.attachEvent( 'on'+type, obj[type+fn] );
    } else
         obj.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
    }

    function setUpFieldEvents(){
         var stripeTables = document.getElementsByClassName("stripe_table");
         var tableBodies = stripeTables.tBodies;

             addEvent(tableBodies, "mouseover", hoverHighlight);
             addEvent(tableBodies, "mouseout", undoHighlight);
    }

    function hoverHighlight(){
            var stripeTables = document.getElementsByClassName("stripe_table");
            var tableBodies = stripeTables.tBodies;
            var tableData = tableBodies.getElementsByTagName("td");
    }

    function undoHighlight(){

    }
```

Answer (score 19):

Have you tried just using the CSS e.g.

```
tr:hover{
 background:red;
}
```

If you want to use jQuery, there's a pretty decent [walkthrough here](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-highlight-table-row-record-on-hover-with-jquery/), if you want pure JS- take a look [here](http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/cssHighlightTableRow/) under the section 'Using Mouse Event Handler and Row Detection'

Comment: As ideal as that method would be, for this, it is not an option.  Practicing my Javascript :/

Comment: @meisterburger You shouldn't use JavaScript unless you really need to. Try practicing it doing something which cannot be achieved using CSS.

Comment: Unfortunately...I _have_ to

Answer (score 1):

Probably can just use [css hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3ahover)

Other option is using javascript (or jquery) [.mouseover](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)
(.mouseenter .mouseleave are probably what you are looking for)

edit:

```
$('tbody#tbodyId tr').mouseenter(function(){/*do stuff */});

So if you wanted to change color I'd do something like

$('tbody#tbodyId tr').mouseenter(function(){
$(this).css('background') = 'red';
});

$('tbody#tbodyId tr').mouseleave(function(){
$(this).css('background') = /*whatever old color was */
});
```

Comment: How would I use mouseover?  Tbody is the event listener and I need to have tr and a elements be the elements that, when hovered over, cause the row they are in to become highlighted VIA css...any thoughts on how this could be achieved?

Comment: Edited main post with examples. Hunters example is better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

If you want, jQuery makes it easy.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tbody class="stripe_table">
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$('.stripe_table').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).addClass('highlight');
  }, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('highlight');
  }
)
```

CSS:

```
.highlight{
    background:red;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kB7u2/1/